# How to update aria2 to latest version 1.18?

Tags: 12.04

My ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS and my installed aria2 version is 1.13.

Today I checked in aria2 website that the latest version is 1.18.

So can I update my aria2 to it's latest version or not?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this PPA:

`ppa:t-tujikawa/ppa`

[Description of repository](https://launchpad.net/~t-tujikawa/+archive/ppa)

Comment: Or try to use the package of a [newer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/aria2) distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Ubuntu 12:04 LTS but aria2 is installed on my Linux version is 1.17.0.

Enter the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:t-tujikawa/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install aria2
```

I hope this helps, at least to increase the latest version of aria2 which you now have.

To see the version:

```
aria2c -v
```